# Using the Django-CMS Wymeditor for ZInnia Entries

Tags: django, django-cms, wymeditor

Is there a way to use the Django-cms WYMeditor (and all of it's plugin capabilities) as the editor for Zinnia?

The goal is to be able to upload photos/videos as content within the entries.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cmsplugin_zinnia/) and add this line to your project settings :

```
ZINNIA_ENTRY_BASE_MODEL = 'cmsplugin_zinnia.placeholder.EntryPlaceholder'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping was possible. It's a shame that I have to do a reset on the zinnia app; I'll need to migrate all of the content. I didn't realize it was possible to "unregister" an Admin class. Now I can really get this to work the way I want. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up changing the AdminModel, since you have to save the model before you can add content. http://snipt.org/vaaia2

Answer (score 0):

I used django-file-picker to get this to work. I had to edit the zinnia/admin/entry.py file according to http://django-file-picker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wymeditor.html

I edited the templates/admin/base_site.html file to have these two lines added to the 'extrastyle' block:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

I had to make sure zinnia wasn't using it's own WYMeditor:

```
ZINNIA_WYSIWYG = None
```

This isn't the ideal solution because I had to actually edit the source files for zinnia, but it'll work for today. I'll look for a more elegant solution next week.